# Setting backgroundcolor to the textfield is not appending the color using ext js

Tags: css, extjs

My code:

```
new Ext.form.TextField({
     value: "Name",
     style: {
         backgroundColor:'red'
     },
     listeners: {
         beforerender: function (e) {
             console.log(e)
             e.setStyle("backgroundColor", "#00cc99");
         }
     }
 });
```

By applying style config or appending color beforerendering doesnt work. Even bodyStyle config is not filling the textbox with color. How to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply custom class to the element and style inner input the way you need:

```javascript
new Ext.form.TextField({
    value: "Name",
    cls: 'red-field'
});
```

And CSS class:

```css
.red-field .x-form-text {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: But I dont want to use cls element here.So is there any alternative.

Comment: Is there a rationale behind that?

Comment: Behind "I don't want to use cls". Because `cls` config option is a standard way of customizing component appearance.

Comment: Yeap, agree. Using classes brings much more flexibility.